# IE: Custom fonts work at first but goes away after reload

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, azure, internet-explorer, caching, https

In IE11, Custom fonts, like bootstrap glyphicons, load at first, but after hitting reload or ctrl+f5, the fonts aren't shown.

All types of font files are added in the css files.

> Checked with network - fonts give result **200**

Environment: Azure

Is there an efficient way to solve this issue?

Comment: Is it possible that you are using multiple fonts for these elements? Fonts may overrule the glyphicon fontfamily

Comment: No. I have added a custom font file. Even that is not loading in azure environment. Locally it works fine.